# Avoid the duplicated data in a particular UITableViewCell after reloading the TableView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using TaglistView to show tags in UITableViewCell.

here is the link for the TaglistView I am using:  https://github.com/ElaWorkshop/TagListView

I need to display my added preferences to the tag list in the UITableViewCell but with the following code that I wrote, whenever I scroll up and back down to the cell the tags are added one more time (My table view has more cells). So for example, if I added 2 preferences, at first they are well displayed, but when I scroll up and down the tag view duplicate the existed tags and i will have 2, then 4, then 6 ...

Hope my question is clear enough

Noting that the tags are editable so I can add or remove some of them.
Any help will be appreciated, I was struggling with it for a long time.

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "morePreferencesCell", for: indexPath) as! MorePreferencesTableViewCell
              
      for tag in self.floorAddedTags!{
          cell.tagList.addTag(tag.first!.key)
     }
}
```

Comment: What type of  `tagList`

Comment: As I mentioned in my question I am using the library "TagListView" , I added the link for it on the Github

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cells are reused remove tags before adding them

```
cell.tagList.removeAllTags()
for tag in self.floorAddedTags!{
   cell.tagList.addTag(tag.first!.key)
}
```

Comment: Wow! it was so simple! Thank you for your help! Actually I was complicating it.